# Why would removing a component affects lifecycle of another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following code example contains 2 components: `Component1` logs `prevState` with `componentDidUpdate` method, `Component2` is removed on a button click to show the use of `componentWillUnmount`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'John',
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(prevState);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>The name is {this.state.name}</div>
        <label htmlFor="prevstate">Type here to see prevState in console: </label>
        <input
          id="prevstate"
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Component2 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Mount');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Unmount');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Click the button to remove the element</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 />
      {showComponent ? <Component2 /> : null}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShowComponent(false);
        }}
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Now I find that these 2 components interfere with each other: clicking the button also logs the `prevState` in the first component. What I thought would happen was that the `componentDidUpdate` method would only monitor the update of Component1, but seems it monitors the button which is outside of both components, why does this happen?

Comment: When you change state with `setShowComponent` in your button, you're actually re-rendering the `<App />` - Therefore the coponents inside it should trigger unmount, mounted, didupdate, etc..

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount Here says `componentDidUpdate` is not called for the initial render?

Comment: Yes, [it's not called for the initial render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Comment: Adding to the comment by @choz, you can use React memo or pure components to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of child components as child components will get called again if any of it’s parent’s state changes as only state updates can tell React to re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the App is rendered, its children are rendered as well.  You might try making Component1 a `React.PureComponent` or defining `shouldComponentUpdate` if you want to reduce the rerendering.

Comment: Do you mean clicking the button triggers a re-render of the `App` component? I disagree cause `componentDidUpdate` is not called on component initial render.

Comment: @thinkvantagedu `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render. [Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: Is re-render `App` equal to updating state of Component1?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu Yes, it does. So choose carefully when you want to re-render. The child-component, and child-component's children are all re-rendered.

Comment: This is surprising, my understanding was re-render equals to an initial render, so `componentDidUpdate()` wouldn't be invoked. Besides state of Component1 is not really updated to anything new.

Comment: Can you give a demo of how to make Component1 to a `React.PureComponent` please?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu You would simply change the inheritance for Component1 from Component to PureComponent.  `class Component1 extends React.PureComponent {...}`